# How to show error message for typing in text box any thing else except number / numeric in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a text box,which only allows to type number,If I try to type alphabet or any special character it should show error below the text box.Once I start typing numeric error should hide.Here I am using reactive form of angular 8. Here is the code below

### home.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col">
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <input type="number" formControlName="title" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.title.errors }"/>

                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.title.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.title.errors.required">Title is required</div>
                    </div>

                </div>

</div>
<div class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary mr-1">Register</button>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="reset" >Cancel</button>
            </div>
</form>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
imageSource :any;
 statusdata: any;
closeResult: string;
registerForm: FormGroup;
    submitted = false;

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.statusdata = [
      { id: 1, name: "cat"},
      { id: 2, name: "arctichare"},
      { id: 3, name: "baboon" },


    ];  
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            title: ['', Validators.required]

        });
  }
  get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }
onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        // display form values on success
        alert('SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n' + JSON.stringify(this.registerForm.value, null, 4));
    }

}
```

### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UsermanagementComponent } from './usermanagement/usermanagement.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/header/header.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UsermanagementComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NgbModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can catch input values with keydown or keyup.

change your input as following:

```
 <input type="number" formControlName="title" class="form-control"
          #inp (keydown)="checkValue($event, inp.value)"
          [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.title.errors }"/>
```

And add following method to your component:

```
checkValue(event: KeyboardEvent, val: any) {

    const allowedChars = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, "Backspace", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight"];
    let isValid: boolean = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < allowedChars.length; i++) {
      if (allowedChars[i] == event.key) {
        isValid = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!isValid) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert('Enter only number'); // or do smt about your error message
    }else{
        //reset error status here
     }

  }
```